# Improving brute-forcing speed

Tags: passwords, brute-force, password-encryption

So I got a salt and a hash, and I know the password has three characters. Is there any better way of getting the password than a triple loop `openssl passwd -salt "$salt" "$i$j$k"`? No dictionary allowed.

Answer (score 0):

No -- although the quickest way to speed it up would be to run this on your computer in a number of threads, maxing out your CPU(s).